# Open a link using JavaScript in iOS safari URL bar

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, safari, mobile-safari

I am attempting to open a link using the iOS safari address/URL bar.

From my testing, the address bar does not execute `javascript:alert("hi");` as it did in previous iOS versions.

Is there a new way of going about this, or was it completely deprecated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems I found my answer, `window.open("https://www.google.com")` for example works in the safari iOS URL bar, while `javascript:alert("hi")` does not.